# Как настроить маршрутизацию (два 3G модема + 3proxy)?

Tags: linux, debian, маршрутизация

ОС: Linux debian 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1 (2017-12-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Имеется три интерфейса:

1. enp0s3 (смотрит в локальную сеть),
2. ppp100 (смотрит в Сеть, 3G модем),
3. ppp200 (смотрит в Сеть, 3G модем).

Вот так выглядит [выдача ifconfig](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5c0ffd666d477fdc38c3ac0d7eac8043).
Настройка [pppd для модема](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4656b0a7a21bd557edce8abde14a9e1f).

Пытаюсь настроить 3proxy для работы через 3G модемы (естественно раздельно). Когда поднимаю только один модем и настраиваю 3proxy, то все работает. Если поднимаю оба модема, то не работает модем, который был поднят первым. Похоже, что проблема в маршрутизации. Однако, как только я не пытался понять и применить настройки - не получилось.

Может кто подскажет, как примерно настроить все это дело? Спасибо.
*Я новичок в Linux, поэтому читать man в моем случае бесполезно.*

Comment: Я правильно понял: надо клиентов локальной сети пустить в интернет через 3proxy, который стоит на сервере с двумя 3G модемами, через которые "приходит" интернет? И как понять фразу в скобках `(естественно раздельно)`?

Comment: @defrag Да, верно, возможно потом будет доступ из Сети по статическому IP адресу (проброшу порты прокси к enp0s3). "Раздельно" имеется ввиду, что буду слушать два порта, например, 8080 и 8081, в зависимости от порта будет пускать трафик по разным модемам (запущу два процесса 3proxy)

Comment: Ок. Но что насчет 2-х 3G модемов? Вы из них хотите некий "балансировщик" собрать? Или резервирование какое-то?

Comment: @defrag мне они нужны для http/https прокси. Никакой балансировки или резервирования

Comment: Это наверно вопрос по мотивам вашей недавней задачи про разделение трафика http/https по разным линкам?

Comment: @defrag да, по этим мотивам

Comment: Новичку как раз man и читать.

Comment: Для proxy никакой настройки маршрутизации не нужно. Настраиваются сервисы в файле конфигурации 3proxy. Объявляется сервис `proxy -a -p3128 -e10.216.75.244` для первого и `proxy -a -p3129 -e10.246.241.31` для второго. Ещё с помощью опции `-i192.168.1.37` можно заставить слушать только на определённом ip-адресе. Можно в одном экземпляре 3proxy сделать 2 и более сервисов, Можно на каздый сервис запускать отдельный proxy. А вообще-то Вы не показали ни одной попытки, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться отвечающим. И не очень-то понятно что вообще хотите получить.

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь, у вас изначально была задумка распределять трафик http/https в зависимости от "входящего" порта. Т.е если пришло на порт 8080 некоего шлюза, то форварднуть на интерфейс ppp0, если на 8081 - то на ppp1.

Поскольку задача требует http-проксирования плюс маскарадинга с учетом порта назначения, то одним iptables или одним http-proxy она не решается. Так как все это работает на разных уровнях модели OSI.

Давайте предложу другой вариант.

Будем анализировать только "исходящий" трафик шлюза.

План будет такой:

- Настраиваем на шлюзе http-proxy (пусть будет 3proxy) для приема коннектов на интерфейсе enp0s3 на стандартный порт 3128.
- Настраиваем браузер клиента на этот http-proxy на порт 3128
- Настраиваем на шлюзе маскарадинг исходящего трафика с учетом порта назначения и выбором соответствующего интерфейса.

Итого получим следующее:

В строке браузера клиента набирается http://microsoft.com, запрос приходит на http-прокси, http-прокси "находит" адрес назначения, отправляет запрос на требуемый сервер, iptables "разруливает" исходящий трафик.

По настройкам:

- 3proxy настраивается максимально просто без авторизации (либо авторизации по ip)
- Браузер клиента настраивается тоже просто (ну вы и сами знаете).
- На шлюзе выполняется примерно следующее: `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp100 -p tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE` и по аналогии для 443 порта.

С виду схема рабочая. Но естественно, я ее не тестировал на ppp соединениях ввиду их отсутствия.

Comment: Проблема похоже решена написанием своего прокси сервера, с привязкой сокета исходящего запроса к определенному интерфейсу с помощью опции SO_BINDTODEVICE. Пока тестирую, вроде работает по задумке, посмотрю как дальше пойдет. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @ВасилийНиконов а киньте сюда свое решение, если не сложно.

Comment: не могу скинуть свой код, т.к. разрабатывал не себя, а для предприятия. Но [вот что помогло мне](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3625#issuecomment-153005680)

Comment: А повесить на разные порты разные сквиды (ну, например сквиды), один из которых имеет tcp_outgoing_address с адресом одного ppp-интерфейса, а другой — другого? Файлики с этой директивой включать в основной конфиг сквида через инклюд и обновлять через ppp-up (т.к. в ней передаётся не имя интерфейса, а его адрес).

Answer (score 0):

Есть решения через netns.

Создаёте бридж. Локалку заслвываете в бридж.

Создаёте пару или несколько пар veth.

Один конец пары засовывается в бридж.

Для вторых концов создавайте netns. Переносите туда интерфейс veth-b и ppp1.

Запускаете скрипт через netns exec который настроит локальную и шлюз по умолчанию в неймспейс и запустит там прокси.

В итоге получите изолированный прокси с разными ip адресами и разными шлюза и на одной машинке.

Тоже самое возможно сделать через контейнеры lxc или docker.